# Git can not clone repository when using bitvise ssh server

Tags: git, ssh

I've installed Git and Bitvise SSH Server, by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3eRlEhzAZk).
First, I've tried this on my home-pc, and it worked fine (clone,push,pull - everything).

After that, I've installed git and bitvise on my work-pc, and after cloning the repository, I get this message:

```
Logon was successful, but only local accounts may connect to Bitvise SSH 
Server when it is operating in personal mode.
```

I believe that this occurs because this Pc is in domain, but I have no idea what really causes this, and how to resolve this.

So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to purchase the Bitvise Standard edition, because of [enforced technical reasons](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-usage-faq#Q020) and to observe their license terms. Or you can use a different SSH server software.